# Графический интерфейс Java

Tags: java, gui

Как реализуют графический интерфейс в Java? Только ли через javax.swing?

Comment: я использую JavaFX

Comment: уже все на JavaFX перешли скорее всего. он удобнее так как можно подключить sceneBuilder и строить визуально формы, как в delphi и прочих оконных приложениях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для Java создано несколько фреймворков для создания **Графического интерфейса пользователя**. Вот наиболее известные:

- **Abstract Window Toolkit (AWT)** - самый первый фреймворк
- **Swing** - фреймворк созданый в 1998 году и пришедший на смену **AWT**
- **Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT)** - фреймворк созданый в 2003 году и активно используемый разработчиками платформы **Eclipse**
- **JavaFX** - изначально это был отдельный язык разработанный в **Sun Microsystems** для создания **Rich Internet Application (RIA)**, но начиная с версии 8 - это просто библиотека включенная в состав стандартной JDK.

Если вы планируете создавать приложения под  Java 8 и выше, то что бы избежать дополнительных зависимостей используйте **JavaFX**. Он хорошо документирован ([JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm)) и по нему есть большое количество руководств ([Официальные руководства](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm)). Для быстрого создания интерфейса вы можете использовать специальный редактор форм [JavaFX Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html).